# Store allocated data alongside allocator on struct

Tags: rust

I want to use the memory allocator `M` to allocate an `Allocated` which is gonna live together with `M` inside a struct. However, I don't want to pollute `UseM` with its lifetime. Is there a way to store `Allocated` inside `UseM`?

```
use std::marker::PhantomData;

pub struct Allocated<'r, T> {
    _phantom: PhantomData<&'r T>
}

pub trait MemPool<'s, 'r, T> {
    fn allocate_default(
        &'s self,
        size: usize,
    ) -> Allocated<'r, T>;
}

struct M<T> {
    _phantom: PhantomData<T>
}

impl<'s, T> MemPool<'s, 's, T> for M<T>
{
    fn allocate_default(
        &'s self,
        size: usize,
    ) -> Allocated<'s, T>{
        todo!()
    }
}

struct UseM<T> {
    //I wanted to allocated with m
    m: M<T>,
    //and store here, withotu `UseM` having to have a lifetime
    allocated: Allocated<'r, T>
}
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8bf2af2f7202a49c196cda98189f6971

```
error[E0261]: use of undeclared lifetime name `'r`
  --> src/lib.rs:32:26
   |
28 | struct UseM<T> {
   |             - help: consider introducing lifetime `'r` here: `'r,`
...
32 |     allocated: Allocated<'r, T>
   |                          ^^ undeclared lifetime
```

Comment: Relevant: [Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32300132/2189130)

Answer (score 2):

This is a “self-referential struct”, a pattern that can't be implemented in safe Rust directly, for two reasons:

1. There is no way to write lifetime annotations that express it, and
2. Structs are allowed to be *moved*, which would invalidate pointers into them, and there's no way to declare “this won't move because it is in a separate  heap allocation” (except for the `Pin` mechanism which is not usable with only safe code).

The crate [`ouroboros`](https://docs.rs/ouroboros/) uses macros and internal unsafe code to provide a safe mechanism to create this type of structure. However, you will have some additional verbosity in accessing the struct, and some things are not possible. Declaring your struct using `ouroboros` would look like this:

```rust
#[ouroboros::self_referencing]
struct UseM<T> {
    m: M<T>,
    #[borrows(m)]
    allocated: Allocated<'this, T>,
}
```